# how to use akeneo-labs spreadsheet-parser to parse large Excel worksheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, akeneo

I downloaded the packages from https://github.com/akeneo/spreadsheet-parser
and when I run it from my [php](/questions/tagged/php) file "as in Usage", I got the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Akeneo\Component\SpreadsheetParser\SpreadsheetParser' not found
```

- P.S. I'm using WAMP the latest version, windows 7

thanks

Comment: Well what does your folder structure look like? What do you have in your PHP file? What does the doc of the lib say about getting started (fyi its composer)?

Comment: what do you mean "my folder structure?" there's nothing but my Xlsx file and the package files.. 
and my PHP file has the code in the Usage tab from the github url.. 
there's no docs there, it's just couple of lines of installation (in Linux pash) and the Usage tab.. and about all of that, I asked for help, if anyone run it in WAMP windows, coz there's only one person in the "Issues" tab was using windows, but with another problem

Comment: The error you have is saying PHP cannot find `SpreadsheetParser` so knowing how you have your folders organized helps us help you. Knowing how you call it in your code helps us help you. If a lib does not have docs you should probably find a different one because it will make your job that much harder.

Comment: yeah I know, but it's the only way to parse 250,000 row, so I've to keep trying with it.. anyways, I contacted with the author, and I figured out that I didn't install composer..  and now I'm trying to install dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted with the author, and I figured out that I didn't install [composer](/questions/tagged/composer)..
and as I don't know anything about it, so he did some edits on his code, and send it to me, so I can use it directly..
anyways, I'll put a snippet of [php](/questions/tagged/php) code, beside that I'll upload the file, to help anyone how face the same problem, and need to parse large worksheet [xlsx](/questions/tagged/xlsx) or [csv](/questions/tagged/csv)

```
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Akeneo\Component\SpreadsheetParser\SpreadsheetParser;

$workbook = SpreadsheetParser::open('FL_insurance_sample.csv');

$myWorksheetIndex = $workbook->getWorksheetIndex('myworksheet');

foreach ($workbook->createRowIterator($myWorksheetIndex) as $rowIndex => $values) {
    echo implode(',',$values);
}
?>
```

- you can download the package directly from here: [csv_parser.zip](http://www.dapompo.hostkda.com/csv_parser.zip)